# How many underscores ('_') in the exported function in C++

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, linker-errors

I have a dll project building in Visual Studio 2015. I use the `.def` file to export the functions. However I am not able to understand how the compiler prefixes the underscores `(_)` to my functions. In some places it adds 1 underscore, in some places 2 and even in some places 3.

I have a function named `Object()` in my code for this Visual Studio seems to generate lot of versions like `__imp____Object`, `__imp___Object` and `__imp__Object`. I can't understand why so many versions.

The problem I am facing is even if I have added `___Object` and `__Object` in my `.def` file I am getting the following linker error:

> `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Object`

Any suggestions, what's going on here.

Comment: if you use *x86* and function is *extern "C" __cdecl*  - single `_` added to name. if you have `Object` - `__imp__Object` must be in lib file

Comment: with single `_` shouldn't it be `__imp_Object` ?

Comment: no, must be exactly `__imp__Object` because `__imp_` always added to name. so `__imp_` + `_` + `Object`

Comment: in *x64* - `__imp_Object` will be - because *x64* not add `_` to name. and better - remove `extern "C"` from declaration. use *c++* names

Comment: THe second part and `x64` I can't do due to project constraints

Comment: With this logic, if I have defined `__Object` in my `.def` file shouldn't it result in `__imp___Object`? My dll builds successfully but if I open my `.lib` in notepad++ I can't see the 3 `_` version. Subsequently, the consuming dll complains for the same

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Good point. But I can't do much about this because this is a legacy project.

Comment: (Reposted because the previous comment was full of typos.) Note that all identifiers that start with an underscore followed by an uppercase and all identifiers that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved. You must not name anything `_Object()` or `__Object()`. `_object()` may be used, provided it is not in the global namespace because identifiers that begin with an underscore in the global namespace are also reserved. See [identifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#In_declarations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the compiler follows a pattern to decorate these exported functions. On a `x86` platform with a `_cdecl calling convention` for every function exported through `.def file` or `__declspec(dllexport)` the `.lib` file contains 2 entries. One as the function name prefixed with an `_` and another prefixed with `__imp__`

For example, if the `def file` has an exported function as `Function1` the lib will have `_Function1` and `__imp__Function1`

This will vary for `x64` and other function calling conventions.

With the above being said, mine was a peculiar case. My def file had `Object`, `_Object` and `__Object` which should result in `_Object`, `__imp__Object`, `__Object`, `__imp___Object`, `___Object` and `__imp____Object`.

Now from the above list, the 2nd actual name (`_Object`) and the the 1st generated name are same, so it was skipping generating symbols for the 2nd name. Hence I was getting the link error:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Object